# mysql: can't find result of a query (into text file)

Tags: php, mysql

I need the results of a mysql query to be piped unto a text file so i can print it. Problen is: Where is
the text file ?! Here is the php code to run the query:

```
enter code here
<?php
// Connect to database server
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mydb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
$sql1 = "SELECT startDate,endDate,intervalTime FROM june2013
INTO OUTFILE 'xxx.txt'";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
    {
     echo "Data added to text file successfully";
    }
else
   {
    echo "Error transfering data " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

After I had ran the above code I recieved the message:

> Data added to text file successfully

Which means the code succeeded in creating the desired text file.
I searched the file in my HD at: xampp/htdocs and couldn't find it ! Then I made a WINDOWS 7 search for
"xxx.txt" and the search found nothing !
So I ran again the code and recieved an error message that says:

> Error transfering data File 'xxx.txt' already exists

If that file exixts, where could it exist if not on my hard disk? If it is on my hard disk why can't I find it?
Could it be some kind of a "hidden file?
Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a server?

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [MySQL select into outfile /tmp no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038170/mysql-select-into-outfile-tmp-no-output)